# how to access json array of objects using foreach loop in javascript and jade

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, pug

I am using foreach loop to show the data of jason array but it take five iterations to show the data but I want to show all the data in single iteration.
How can I do so? Here is jade file code.

each item in data

```
                td 
                    a.three(href='')
                        |#{item}
```

In first iteration item contains :"youtube#searchListResponse".

In second iteration item contains : " \"BDC7VThyM9nfoSQm1_kOyhtJTEw/0MX1aovXL6JrPZ_tgqxLQ_YhGWI\"".

In third iteration item contains :"CAIQAA".

I want to access id or thumbnail in first iteration but it returns error. How can i access it in first iteration using above jade code? Is it possible or not? 
here is link of jason array (
https://gist.github.com/paulomcnally/620b76a9afe81f56e8c9
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse your array first using `JSON.parse(json["items"])`
Then access your data if you want a specific index  `json_array[0]["id"]` or `json_array[0]["snippet"]["thumbnails"]`